# Conversion of spherical coordinates to cartesian

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

For the flow $A = \frac{c}{r}$ with $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ I wanted to calculate the velocity field with $\nabla A$
As a result I get $(-\frac{c}{r^2},0,0)$. So far so good. When I tried converting it to cartesian coordinates I'm stuck. 
I would have inserted the given $r$ in my solution however wolfram alpha & the solution suggest the solution in cartesian coordinates is:
[image]

Converting with $x=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \cos(0)$ does not really work. I'm sure I'm currently having a major blackout in seeing something elemental missing here.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586848/how-to-obtain-the-gradient-in-polar-coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply convert your expression for polar coordinates to cartesian because the operator is different in the systems. But the cartesian calcuation is easy (using $c=1$):
$$\nabla A  = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}A, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}A\right)
= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)
= \left(\frac{-x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}, \frac{-y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks! I know that using cartesian coordinates is not really a hassle however doing it in polar coordinates is easier. I thought since wolfram alpha showed the conversion that there is a way to convert the solutions. The flow stays the same anyway, I just use a different system to describe it, thus I should be able to describe my velocity field in both systems as well. Or would I have to convert beforehand as you did to get both results? I thought the operator is different to cover for the differences in the systems.