# How to obtain mean gradient in polar coordinates when Poisson/Gaussian process?

Tags: calculus, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, polar-coordinates

I am thinking how to deduct the mean gradient in polar coordinates if the process itself is Poisson/Gaussian/... 
The basic deduction of the gradient is in the thread [How to obtain the gradient in polar coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/586848/17474) so the gradient operator is

\begin{equation}
\nabla =\hat{\pmb e}_{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}+\hat{\pmb e}_{\theta}\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}.
\end{equation}

I am thinking how I should proceed here. 
I am monitoring confounders of multifactorial processes. 
I can plot many of them separately but I would like characterise an individual process by a mean vector.